# Why is this code producing an invalid Excel file?

Tags: java, excel

This creates a excel file which gives file format is not valid error when trying to handle it, not proper excel file with a number added on it:

```
public static void write () throws IOException, WriteException { 
  WorkbookSettings settings = new WorkbookSettings(); 
  File seurantaraportti = new File("ta.xls"); 
  WritableWorkbook seurw = Workbook.createWorkbook(ta,settings); 
  seurw.createSheet("ta", 0); 
  WritableSheet ws = seurw.getSheet(0); 
  addNumber(ws,0,0,100.0); 
  seurw.close(); 
} 

private static void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row, Double d) 
    throws WriteException, RowsExceededException { 
  Number number=new Number(column, row,d); 
  sheet.addCell(number); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what library are you using? this is not standard Java libs.

Comment: what's the *ta* variable (either it's not visible either, or you rewrote this and that wouldn't even compile). And *seurantaraportti* is unused. Is it supposed to be *ta*?

Answer (score 4):

You are not writing anything to the workbook. you are missing

> seurm.write()

before closing the workbook

> seurw.close();

Below is the working code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;
import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

public class WriteExcel {

    public static void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
        WorkbookSettings settings = new WorkbookSettings();
        // settings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
        File ta = new File("ta.xls");
        WritableWorkbook seurw = Workbook.createWorkbook(ta, settings);
        seurw.createSheet("ta", 0);
        WritableSheet ws = seurw.getSheet(0);
        addNumber(ws, 0, 0, 100.0);
        seurw.write(); // You missed this line.
        seurw.close();
    }

    private static void addNumber(WritableSheet sheet, int column, int row,
            Double d) throws WriteException, RowsExceededException {
        Number number = new Number(column, row, d);
        sheet.addCell(number);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            write();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

writableWorkbook seurw = Workbook.createWorkbook(ta,settings);

must be

writableWorkbook seurw = Workbook.createWorkbook("ta",settings);

Comment: -1: It's obvious that the code wouldn't even compile if it really looked like that, so it's a typo. If you really want to correct this, write it as a comment. Posting answers that aren't an answer only prevents other people who might be able to help from looking at the question.

Comment: wont it compile with a undefined var? Did the other answer not mention exactly the same??

Comment: Not it won't compile with an undefined variable in Java (except if you use the Eclipse compiler which allows partial compilation, but you still wouldn't be able to run the program). Chiccodoro's point is valid, though I find the reaction a bit harsh as we were just trying to lead the OP to clarify his question. That being said I deleted my answer as someone posted a solution now that the problem has been clarified.

Comment: @haylem: I don't mean to be harsh, but if as you say my point is valid, what's wrong with downvoting? It's nothing else than rating the answer, and since the answer doesn't help at all but turns a question with "0 answers" to one with "2 answers" or more which can mislead some people not to view it at all, it would be better for the OP if there was no answer at all. Thus my rating.

Comment: @chiccodoro: and thus my own deletion :) I do agree with you, and that's also why after posting my question I realized that simply asking for details in a comment to the question itself was better (I'm new here). I didn't mind the intent of your downvote and comment. Harsh was maybe too strong a word. Maybe just "blunt" :)

Comment: @haylem: Maybe "harsh" was a bit "harsh", or is that too harsh? :-)

Comment: hmmm, trying to help here. I dont care about the downvote. I recognized a error in the code, posted it and get a whole bunch of crap over me.